# MissingPluginException on Flutter app when calling the native activity for the second time

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, native

On my flutter app, I invoke a method call to a native android activity that's deals with scanning a PDF417, decoding the information, and basically, through a route, displays the information on a flutter component. This works fine, however, when I try to do this a second time, I get the MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method StartSecondActivity on channel com.test_ops).

My call from flutter looks like this:

```
  try {
    String result = await platform.invokeMethod('StartSecondActivity');
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    print(e.message);
  }
```

and my MainActivity.java is set up as this:

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private static final String CHANNEL = "com.test_ops";

    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);

        flutterEngine.getNavigationChannel().setInitialRoute("/wb");

        FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().put("cab_flutter_id", flutterEngine);

        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
        .setMethodCallHandler((call, result) -> {
            if(call.method.equals("StartSecondActivity")){

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntentWedgeSample.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                //result.success("ActivityStarted");
            }else{
                //result.notImplemented();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Which executes great, no problem here. Everything works as intended.
To return from the IntentWedgeSample activity, I execute the following code:

```
    startActivity(
            FlutterActivity
                    .withNewEngine()
                    .initialRoute("/wb")
                    .build(IntentWedgeSample.this)

    );
```

This, does indeed, return to the flutter app and displays the info gathered from the native component. However, when I try to execute this a second time, it gives me that error.

I've tried clearing the stack. That didn't work.
I've checked that the flutter activity has been declared in the manifest. Which it does:

```
<activity
    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"
    android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
 android:configChanges= "orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
/>
```

I've tried cleaning, pub-getting etc, with no avail.
Rechecked my routes.
I tried returning with a cached engine, but then the app exits unexpectedly.

```
startActivity(
 FlutterActivity
   .withCachedEngine("cab_flutter_id")
   .build(IntentStartActivity.this)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end we found that neither MethodChannel, Platform Messages, nor the Navigator helped with this. We used **android_intent_plus** instead, which allowed us to do concurrent calls to the activity without getting that error.

So instead of:

```
try {
    String result = await platform.invokeMethod('StartSecondActivity');
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    print(e.message);
  }
```

Bypassing the MethodChannel from the main activity, we first declared our AndroidIntent and make a call directly to the **IntentWedgeSample**:

```
AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
  action: 'android.intent.action.ACTION_VIEW',
  package: 'com.test_ops',
  componentName: 'com.test_ops.IntentWedgeSample',
);
```

Instead of invoking, we just called the launch method to this:

```
await intent.launch()
```

As simple as that. The activity returned, the results were already on a mutually shares Sqlite database, and the error was no more.

I hate using 3rd party components to achieve something that worked before, but alas, this is our solution. Credit has to go to **fiddich77**.